# How to run sbt, evaluate expressions and leave?

Tags: sbt, sh

I want to run this shell script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

set -e

sbt <<_EOF_
set name := "foo"
set organization := "bar"
publish
_EOF_
```

I don't want interactive mode, when i run this script sbt doesn't stop working after last line.
How to pass multiple set expressions in way like that and leave interactive mode? I need to pass many set parameters in this script, i don't know the best way

UPDATE:
publish command may fail. 
I want this scenario: if it fails then sh script would have non zero exit, otherwise exit 0 (no errors)

Answer (score 1):

Use [SBT batch mode](https://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Running.html#Batch+mode) specifying a space-separated list of sbt commands as arguments:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
set -e
sbt 'set name := "foo"' 'set organization := "bar"' publish
```

If `publish` throws, say, `java.lang.RuntimeException: Repository for publishing is not specified`, then `echo $?` should return non-zero exit code.

Comment: publish command may fail. I want this scenario: if it fails then sh script would have non zero exit, otherwise exit 0 (no errors)

Comment: The exit status of a script is the exit status of the last command in the script. With `set -e` the script will fail explicitly if `sbt` fails.